# Visual Studio doesn't show the latest code - Potential cache issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, caching, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

So this is is a weird issue I'm facing.

I pull the latest code-base from the version-controlled repository (using Azure DevOps, but don't think it matters), and the code that I see in Visual Studio is *not* updated to the latest!

I think this is some sort of a caching issue, the file on disk is updated but VS is holding on to the older version!
So my question is, how can I force a refresh on the VS cache? Is there a trick to forcing VS to clear its cache?

**Verification:**

- I verified the code-base has the latest code by just opening the repo in the browser and navigating to a couple of files that I know have been updated.
- I also verified that the latest code has been pulled to my local system by navigating to the file and just opening it in Notepad++, confirming that it is the same as the repo.

**Measures taken:** None of these worked!

- Visual Studio restarted
- Machine restarted
- Checked for Windows Updates (none available)
- Deleted the local main branch and checked out the remote main branch
- Created a new local branch based off of the remote main branch
- Did a hard-reset to a couple of commits before the latest

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019, version 16.10.4
- .NET Framework, version 4.8.04084
- Running VS as Admin

Comment: Soo.. Are you asking, or telling?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't "cache" files. It shows the contents of files on your disk. You can find out where a file is by right clicking on the file's tab. It might be showing a file location that you're not expecting.

Comment: @CaiusJard Both :) Sharing what I experienced so others can resolve their issues, and also looking for better answers.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah that's what I found out through my research as well. For my validation, I navigated to the actual file path through VS as you suggested and the discrepancy was present; File opened in Notepad++ showed a different version compared to what VS showed.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really set up for "blog" style content where you find some problem, write about it then talk about the solution. You're free to come across a unique problem, put some effort into solving it and then pose it as a question and then also post an answer to it, but you should not include solutions within questions. As is this question lacks some concrete  research and proof that there was/is something wrong with VS; it seems anecdotal (a story) without a clear question and a solution of "try turning it off and on again" and as such I'm not sure it's particularly useful..

Comment: *Visual Studio doesn't "cache" files* - hmm, I think though it might (in some contexts) appear that it does - consider that one clicks "no" to the "external file has changed; reload it?" dialog; you end up with a discord between what VS shows and what is on disk. Not saying that definitely happened here but there is a general lack of research/evidence to the question, that something beyond "yeah, that's a feature" behavior was at play, IMHO

Comment: @CaiusJard I appreciate your time and effort in writing a detailed comment, however I do disagree with you. This is an issue that others may experience and here is a solution. On the other hand, there is a clear issue encountered, validation steps, what worked and what didn't! If someone else had posted this previously, it would have save me hours of debugging. Additionally, there's a clear question, I want to know how this happens and how to mitigate it in a systematical way. I appreciate your input and try to be more precise in my next question, and will edit this post accordingly.

Comment: @CaiusJard *you end up with a discord between what VS shows and what is on disk* - So you may have seen a similar behaviour in a different context. Are there any resources you can point me to?

Comment: Only the process: open a file in VS, make a change, open a file in Notepad and make a change *and save it* - VS presents a dialog of "the file was modified externally and has changes here- what to do?" With option to not "keep the VS modified version open" - on disk it looks like A, in VS it looks like B, but I'm not sure I've seen it 1) hide the unsaved changes indicator such that it misleads you into thinking it's showing the latest file on disk and 2) persist the memory of the modification across gracefulnrestarts of VS and machine.. but maybe it is holding onto your unsaved changes for you

Comment: I just had what I thought was a similar thing in one of my projects; the file Xyz.cs in SourceTree looked like one thing and the Xyz.cs in VS was different; changes SourceTree said the file had weren't visible on VS. I was pulling my hair until I noticed some muppet has duplicated the file into a different but nearly identically named folder 3 directories up so SourceTree was telling me `c:\repos\x\tests\controller\account\xyz.cs` had 600 lines and Vs was telling me `c:\repos\x\unittests\controller\account\xyz.cs` had 500 lines, identical to the first 500 of the other file. Sigh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround and get this fixed.

This is what worked for me: Go to Task Manager, navigate to Details tab, find VS (in my case "devenv.exe"), right click and End Process Tree. Run VS again and the code is up to date.

*Nuclear Option:* Delete the entire project from the local machine and clone it again. I didn't need to do this as it was fixed by the Task Manager solution, but this is the other option I had in mind.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled why "VS restart" and "Machine restart" didn't work to resolve the problem but killing VS on task manager did; are you asserting that VS would somehow persist its "memory" of a file of shut down gracefully(and restore the memory when launched again) but not if killed instantly?

Comment: Yeah I think that is the case. VS somehow knows what files I had open in my project, so when I restart my machine and open the project in VS again, all the files I had previously open are opened again. So this information is somehow persisting on file. However, I don't know what kinda data VS saves in memory, so I'm not necessarily claiming that it's definitely happening, but this is what I saw and the steps I took. Still baffled by it.

Comment: The only thing I can think might explain your problem is the "recover recent unsaved files" mechanism yanking your chain